# AWS S3 access only for Cognito users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I have a react app where users should be able to upload files to and list files from S3 buckets. I implemented Cognito auth using [this](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js) package and I want to allow only logged users to upload and list files. On the AWS side, I have multiple API Gateway endpoints that trigger lambda (Node JS) function which saves/gets files on/from S3 bucket. I guess I'll use Cognito authorizer to secure API endpoints. My question is: how to save files to and get files from specific S3 bucket folder (prefix) and to restrict that user can access only objects from their own folder?

I have read many articles and docs but I haven't been able to find the right solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be aware of a couple of options here. One is to use Amplify, which would allow your client to talk directly to S3 (without proxying those requests through your Lambda backend) and the other is for your backend to vend S3 pre-signed URLs to your client (for the same reason).

Comment: @jarmod I'm using a pre-signed URL for uploading to S3 but how could I save the file with username prefix for example?

Comment: The pre-signed URL for PUT/POST includes the prefix (actually the full object key). Your backend dictates this entirely and this is how you can restrict a given user to their specific prefix in S3.

Comment: @jarmod thanks! what about GET req for listing objects, should I use presign-URL also?

Comment: You can pre-sign ListObjects requests as far as I know but I haven't used it. Try it and see if it gives you what you need. I'd expect you to be able to supply the prefix too.